# Magento 2: Error during compilation

Tags: magento2, compiler, di, setup-di-compile, compilation

I have below error while running

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

```
Errors during compilation:
        Custom\Module\Block\BuyingListIndex
                Incorrect dependency in class Custom\Module\Block\BuyingListIndex in D:/wamp/www/smint/magento/app/code/Custom/Module/Block/BuyingListIndex.php
\Magento\Framework\Filesystem already exists in context object
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface already exists in context object
        Custom\Module\Block\CategoryListIndex
                Incorrect dependency in class Custom\Module\Block\CategoryListIndex in D:/wamp/www/smint/magento/app/code/Custom/Module/Block/CategoryListIndex.php
\Magento\Framework\Filesystem already exists in context object
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface already exists in context object
        Custom\Module\Block\EtradeIndex
                Incorrect dependency in class Custom\Module\Block\EtradeIndex in D:/wamp/www/smint/magento/app/code/Custom/Module/Block/EtradeIndex.php
\Magento\Framework\Filesystem already exists in context object
        Custom\Module\Block\MyModule\BuyingList
                Incorrect dependency in class Custom\Module\Block\MyModule\BuyingList in D:/wamp/www/smint/magento/app/code/Custom/Module/Block/MyModule/BuyingList.php
\Magento\Framework\Filesystem already exists in context object
        Custom\Module\Block\MyModule\Edit
                Incorrect dependency in class Custom\Module\Block\MyModule\Edit in D:/wamp/www/smint/magento/app/code/Custom/Module/Block/MyModule/Edit.php
\Magento\Framework\Filesystem already exists in context object
        Custom\Module\Block\MyModule\EditMessage
                Incorrect dependency in class Custom\Module\Block\MyModule\EditMessage in D:/wamp/www/smint/magento/app/code/Custom/Module/Block/MyModule/EditMessage.php
\Magento\Framework\Filesystem already exists in context object
        Custom\Module\Block\MyModule\Index
                Incorrect dependency in class Custom\Module\Block\MyModule\Index in D:/wamp/www/smint/magento/app/code/Custom/Module/Block/MyModule/Index.php
\Magento\Framework\Filesystem already exists in context object
        Custom\Module\Block\Posts\ViewPosts
                Incorrect dependency in class Custom\Module\Block\Posts\ViewPosts in D:/wamp/www/smint/magento/app/code/Custom/Module/Block/Posts/ViewPosts.php
\Magento\Framework\Filesystem already exists in context object
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface already exists in context object
        Custom\Module\Block\SellingListIndex
                Incorrect dependency in class Custom\Module\Block\SellingListIndex in D:/wamp/www/smint/magento/app/code/Custom/Module/Block/SellingListIndex.php
\Magento\Framework\Filesystem already exists in context object
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface already exists in context object
        Custom\Module\Block\UserPostsListIndex
                Incorrect dependency in class Custom\Module\Block\UserPostsListIndex in D:/wamp/www/smint/magento/app/code/Custom/Module/Block/UserPostsListIndex.php
\Magento\Framework\Filesystem already exists in context object
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface already exists in context object
        Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Messages\Grid\Collection
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface. Actual type: \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface; File:
D:/wamp/www/smint/magento/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Messages/Grid/Collection.php

        Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Posts\Grid\Collection
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface. Actual type: \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface; File:
D:/wamp/www/smint/magento/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Posts/Grid/Collection.php

Total Errors Count: 12
```

`D:/wamp/www/smint/magento/app/code/Custom/Module/Block/BuyingListIndex.php` Code

```
namespace Custom\Module\Block;

class BuyingListIndex extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, \Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Posts\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory, \Custom\Module\Model\Posts $posts, \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem, \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory, \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->posts = $posts;
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->_imageFactory = $imageFactory;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
         parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
}
```

**[UPDATE]**

**app\code\Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Posts\Grid\Collection.php**

```
namespace Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Posts\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\AggregationInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Posts\Collection as PostsCollection;

/**
 * Collection for displaying grid of etrade posts
 */
class Collection extends PostsCollection implements SearchResultInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool $metadataPool,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $storeManager,
            $metadataPool,
            $connection,
            $resource
        );
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }
}
```

How to solve above complication errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with below code,

Remove var folder and run command of compile,

```
class BuyingListIndex extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Posts\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory, 
    \Custom\Module\Model\Posts $posts,
    \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory,
    array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->posts = $posts;
        $this->_filesystem = $context->getFilesystem();
        $this->_imageFactory = $imageFactory;
        $this->scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
         parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: try with updated code

Comment: Hi @Rakesh. Seems works. Let me check for All files :)

Comment: `Custom\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Messages\Grid\Collection
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface. Actual type: \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface; File:
D:/wamp/www/smint/magento/app/code/Custom/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Messages/Grid/Collection.php` for this?

Comment: which error are display after updating above code?

Comment: Hi @Rakesh. Your code is working fine. I have total 12 Errors. 11 are solved by ur code. 1 is remaining which i posted in Comment. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, Updated question please look in to that u will get better idea for last error

Answer (score 2):

That's the beauty of dependency injection that you don't end up using same class multiple times :)

Look at the following two classes and you will find all the functions you need

**vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/Context.php**

**vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Context.php**

For example you can call the followings in your constructor

***$context->getLogger()*** which means you don't need ***\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger***

or

***$context->getStoreManager()*** which means you don't need ***\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface***

Comment: This is actually the better answer. It's important to understand why something goes wrong, rather than only getting a solution without understanding the error. The problem here is that your constructor includes a dependency that's already provided in the context object. Magento detects this and throws an error, thus preventing you from loading the identical class twice and wasting precious resources.